# How do I add textures to an imported model?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, obj

I am new to Blender and need help adding textures to a complex sailing ship model downloaded from CGTrader. The ship is going to be added to an ocean scene that I am working on.

[image]

The model has over 600,000 polygons

It also comes with 16 different sets of textures to apply to it. I'm basing this number on the number of normal files it came with.

[image]

I reduced the size of the object to get a better view of it.
I searched for tutorials on YouTube to learn how to apply textures to a complex object, but I couldn't find anything that was helpful.
I've searched YouTube to learn how to texture an object, but I can't seem to find anything helpful.

Blender crashes when performing actions in edit mode.
The UV map also looks like a mess.

[image]

I'm just trying to map the proper textures to the proper parts of the object so I can add it to my scene but I'm struggling to even begin how to do that.

Do I have to select each face and vertex of the individual pieces in edit mode and separate them as objects to apply textures?

Did I download the wrong type of model for this purpose by mistake?

Comment: Maybe you can break it up into several questions?
I can't seem to find the right answer for you.
For example: 
How to map the textures for the model?
How to reduce the polycount of the model?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This answer only addresses the question of how to add textures to a complex model.**
To enable the Node Wrangler add-on, go to Edit >
Preferences > Add-ons and search for 'Node Wrangler'.
Once enabled, select your Principled BSDF in the Shading tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the Blender File View. From there, select the textures you want to import and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.
This will add and map all selected textures.
You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to access Node Wrangler.
[This tutorial](https://youtu.be/uhcOrnnc6YY?si=6lxa7dA7vdiyQgCv) is a good explanation of the topic.
[image: Node Wrangler menu]

Comment: PS: No, you don't need to separate the parts of the model, my method may not work after you edit the model.

Comment: I don't really get how this is an answer to the (admittedly broad) question. The OP seems to struggle more with the complexity or amount of materials rather than the application of a single texture. Besides, this doesn't even really address that part.

Comment: How can I improve my answer? I answered how to apply textures to an object, but didn't mention anything about the type of model OP is using. The model has quite a high polycount, it's really difficult to use as OP says.